# Entity Framework Core ForeignKeyAttribute on both sides

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an application with Entity Framework Core with different entities in my context, but there are two of them that require a one-to-zero-or-one relation. My way of doing that and ensuring validation was to do something like the following:

```
public class PurchasedPackage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PurchasedPackageModifier))]
    public int? PurchasedPackageModifierId { get; set; }

    public virtual PurchasedPackageModifier PurchasedPackageModifier { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class PurchasedPackageModifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PurchasedPackage))]
    public int PurchasedPackageId { get; set; }

    public virtual PurchasedPackage PurchasedPackage { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Where `PurchasedPackage` is required and `PurchasedPackageModifier` is optional. By specifying `ForeignKey` attribute on both sides I'm trying to ensure data integrity across saves to both tables so nobody creates a `PurchasedPackage` with a non-existent `PurchasedPackageModifier` and vice versa.

While this works as required I'm getting warnings in my logs stating the following:

```
'PurchasedPackage.PurchasedPackageModifier' and 'PurchasedPackageModifier.PurchasedPackage' were separated into two relationships as ForeignKeyAttribute was specified on properties 'PurchasedPackageModifierId' and 'PurchasedPackageId' on both sides.
```

And

```
'PurchasedPackageModifier.PurchasedPackage' and 'PurchasedPackage.PurchasedPackageModifier' were separated into two relationships as ForeignKeyAttribute was specified on properties 'PurchasedPackageId' and 'PurchasedPackageModifierId' on both sides.
```

My question is: am I doing this right and should I ignore these warnings in this particular case or there is a better way of achieving same validation/integrity behavior?

Comment: `Where PurchasedPackage is required and PurchasedPackageModifier is optional. By specifying ForeignKey attribute on both sides I'm trying to ensure data integrity across saves to both tables so nobody creates a PurchasedPackage with a non-existent PurchasedPackageModifier and vice versa.` This is a bit contradicting to me, so if you can't create one without the other then nothing is optional, or am I missing something?

Comment: @cantSleepNow with MSSQL 2 FKs are created, one for each table. As for the required/optional question - PurchasedPackage can have zero or one PurchasedPackageModifier, which, in turn, cant exist without a PurchasedPackage. One can create/update PurchasedPackage without a modifier, but if modifier is supplied it should be checked for integrity. PurchasedPackageModifier must always contain PurchasedPackage to which it is applied to.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll edit the answer accordingly

Answer (score 9):

You’re doing it the right way. According to Microsoft, the reason a warning is shown is because most of the time it's a mistake to put foreign keys on two tables that reference each other, unless of course you're creating a one-to-one relationship. Here's a quote from an Engineering Manager for Entity Framework at Microsoft:

> The warning is basically saying that using ForeignKeyAttribute in this
> way creates two relationships because it is not uncommon for people to
> do this by mistake not intending it to create two relationships.
>
> https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11756#issuecomment-383640800

To suppress the warning, make a call to `DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings()` in your `DbContext` class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;

public sealed class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    /* DbContext code... */
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder Builder)
    {
        Builder.ConfigureWarnings(delegate (WarningsConfigurationBuilder warnings)
        {
            // The following line will suppress the warning
            // "'Foo.Bar' and 'Bar.Foo' were separated into two relationships as
            // ForeignKeyAttribute was specified on properties 'BarId' and
            // 'FooId' on both sides."
            warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.ForeignKeyAttributesOnBothNavigationsWarning);
        });
    }
    /* DbContext code... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11756) about warnings is closed in April 2018. I did try your two classes now with mysql(pomelo lib) and indeed I get one FK. So if this is acceptable to you you can ignore the warnings (to quote one of the devs from that github link)

If you really want the "one-to-zero-or-one relation", then the following approach is how I'd do it:

- `PurchasedPackage` has no FK to `PurchasedPackageModifier`, by this I mean remove both `int? PurchasedPackageModifierId` and the navigation property `urchasedPackageModifier PurchasedPackageModifier` - this covers 1-0 part where a record in `PurchasedPackage` can exist without corresponding `PurchasedPackageModifier` existing
- `PurchasedPackageModifier` has a column `PurchasedPackageId` which is FK to `PurchasedPackage` and also an unique index - this covers 1-1 part where

Comment: I do want one-to-zero-or-one indeed, the problem is if i skip FK on PurchasedPackage then one can save PurchasedPackage entity with PurchasedPackage.PurchasedPackageModifierId set to any invalid value that doesn't correspond to any existing Id in PurchasedPackageModifier table

Comment: edit the answer after this comment as well. Initially by removing the FK I've meant that you remove both the int propery and the navigation property.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that my 2 options are either having 2 FKs or removing access to PurchasedPackageModifier on PurchasedPackage entirely?

Comment: I don't know if these are the only 2 :) But 2 FKs in this case seems a bit weird. Maybe look at the use cases covered with my idea: 1-  You can have a `PurchasedPacakge` that doesn't have `PurchasedPackageModifier` and you can query for such entries. 2- If you have  `PurchasedPackageModifier` corresponding `PurchasedPacakge` entry ahs to exist (thanks to FK) and it can have exactly one of it (thanks to UniqueIDX), you can also query for all PPs that have a PPM.

Comment: So you don't remove access, because ther is no access needed in that way, if you do simply PP JOIN PPM you get all PPs that have PPM, if you do PP LEFT JOIN PPM WHERE INSULL(PPM) (pseudo code obviously) you can get all PPs that don't have a PPM. Which is all that you need. So look for existince of a PPM by using two tables instead of one